# Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of '<tr>'

Tags: angular5

i have type **tr *ngFor="let data for prescription">** in my desplay page.
but having error `Uncaught Error: Template parse error.`i'm using angular 5 and unable to start loop in .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually i made mistake in syntax i wrote **ngFor="let data for prescription"** but i should write `of` instead of `for`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong. If you want to use for loop in `Angular` then you need to use `*ngFor`.
i.e.
`<tr *ngFor="let test of testData">
<td>{{test?.id}}</td>
</tr>`
Make sure, you import `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` in your app module.

Comment: i had already import that but i found my mistake it shouldn't be `for` or `from` . thanks

Comment: Ohk. Good to hear.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use ***of*** instead of ***for***

try: *ngFor="let data of prescription"

Comment: thank you very much. i didn't see your post and before that i found my mistake.